# Can we increase RAM, CPU as per our requirements in AWS EC2?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

Can we increase RAM, CPU as per our requirements in AWS EC2?
Like customize increasing memory which is possible in vmware

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. You have to select one of the offered [EC2 instance types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

Comment: If in case requirement come to increase memory and cpu then what to do on existing instance?

Comment: Stop the machine, select another type, start again, takes about 2min downtime. (Avoiding that is possible but more complicated.) -- Maybe you just try it out and/or read the fine manual: [Resizing Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html)

Comment: Thanks, It works but there are lot of limitations. What about if only disk space need to increase from existing instance?